# rails_admin has_many through with extra field

Tags: many-to-many, rails-admin, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models. `User` and `Project`. And there is a many_to_many relation with and extra `position` field between them. I can't see that extra field on rails_admin edit page.

How can add that field to form?

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects, :through => :works_ons
```

**project.rb**

```
has_many :users, :through => :works_ons
```

**works_on.rb**

```
attr_accessible :position, :project_id, :user_id

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it true that your user model `has_many :users, :through => :works_ons?`

I'm wondering if you need

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects, :through => :works_ons
```

Comment: Edited the question to add your suggestion.

Comment: Could you clarify: you can't see that field on the navigation panel, or you can't see that field from the project or user edit page?

If the latter, you may need to add the following to your rails_admin.rb:


**rails_admin.rb**


        config.model 'Project' do
          configure :works_ons do
          visible true
        end
      end

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I found. You should probably add a custom field below the association and enter the extra fields.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Has-many-%3Athrough-association